# Find a minimum of a variance

Tags: probability, statistics

Given $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, linearly independent.

$Y_1$ has mean $\theta$ and variance $\sigma_1^2$, and $Y_2$ has mean $\theta$ and variance $\sigma_2^2$

Given $Y_3 = a Y_1 + (1-a) Y_2$

So then by definition, $V(Y_3) = a^2 V(Y_1) + (1-a)^2 V(Y_2) = a^2 \sigma_1^2 + (1-a)^2 \sigma_2^2$

By question is now how will I be able to find $a$ such that $V(Y_3)$ is at a minimum value? It's an equation with two $\sigma$s so I'm not too sure what to do.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is $0\le α \le 1$ to be assumed?

Comment: no sir @Stefanos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\sigma_1^2$ and $\sigma_2^2$ are presumed fixed constants.  So, we wish to minimize ${\rm Var}[Y_3] = a^2 \sigma_1^2 + (1-a)^2 \sigma_2^2$ with respect to $a$.  Any minimum must occur at some critical point; i.e., for some $a$ satisfying $$\frac{d}{da}\left[a^2 \sigma_1^2 + (1-a)^2 \sigma_2^2\right] = 0.$$  Thus, we must have $2a \sigma_1^2 = 2(1-a)\sigma_2^2$, or $$ a = \frac{\sigma_2^2}{\sigma_1^2 + \sigma_2^2}.$$  It is then left to you to verify that this is in fact a minimum, either by considering the second derivative, or some other means.

Comment: thanks, i forgot the fact that $\sigma$s are constants.

Comment: @heropup Thanks for the correction +10 from me

Answer (score 1):

In order to minimize the variance of $Y_3$, you should consider the function $$f(α):=α^2σ_1^2+(1-α)^2σ_2^2$$ and minimize it with respect to $α$. The first derivative is $$f'(α)=2ασ_1^2-2(1-α)σ_2^2=2α(σ_1^2+σ_2^2)-2σ_2^2$$ with root $$α=\frac{σ_2^2}{σ_1^2+σ_2^2}$$ The second derivative is $$f''(α)=2(σ_1^2+σ_2^2)>α$$ for all $α \in \mathbb R$ and therefore in the critical point $f$ has a minimum as required.

Comment: Your algebra is incorrect:  the function is $a^2 \sigma_1^2 + (1-a)^2 \sigma_2^2$, not $a^2 \sigma_1^2 + (1-a^2) \sigma_2^2$.  This should be obvious simply by observing that the variance of $Y_3$ is never negative, which your expression is not consistent with.

Comment: @heropup Only the case 1. was false, thanks for pointing it.

Comment: @heropup Sorry, there must be more mistakes